# What is the difference between input().strip().split() and input().split()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, strip

Split() function uses whitespace string as separator and removes the empty strings, so I think there is no use using strip() or rstrip() function to remove extra whitespace in head or tail. And here is my example:

```
a = ' \n   1 2 3 4     \n\n 5 \n\n \t'
b = a.rstrip().split()
c = a.split()
print('b =',b)
print('c =',c)
```

The result turns out to be:

```
b = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
c = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

It seems that there is no difference in betweeen. However, the former one( `intput().strip().split()`) seems more widely used. So what is the difference in these two expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference. `split()` ignores whitespace on the ends of the input by default. People call `strip()` first either because they think it's clearer or because they don't know this behavior of `split()`.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

Comment: As a side note, this is not clearly documented for Python 2, hence the confusion: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split

Comment: @Selcuk: Yup, I'd probably call `strip()` too if I'd only seen those docs.

Comment: There's no difference in *the output* if you use the default parameters for `.strip()` and `.split()`, but that will not always be the case.

Compare these examples:

    `a = ' \n 1,2,3,4,5 \n\n \t'`
    `b = a.strip().split(',')`
    `c = b.split(',')`
    `print(b)`
    `# Out: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`
    `print(c)`
    `# Out: [' \n 1', '2', '3', '4', '5 \n\n \t']`

Also, while just using `.split()` is a useful shortcut, `.strip().split()` more clearly explains what is happening.